# Docker installation

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dependencies

I tried to install docker with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install docker* -y
```

but I got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
docker-ce : Conflicts: docker.io but 19.03.8-0ubuntu1.20.04.2 is to be installed
 docker-ce-cli : Conflicts: docker.io but 19.03.8-0ubuntu1.20.04.2 is to be installed
 docker.io : Depends: containerd (>= 1.2.6-0ubuntu1~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

What does this implies and how do i resolve it? I saw similar response, but I still have same problem.

Thank you,
Tony

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Really you have to decide which version of Docker you need. Install `docker.io` package (older, from official Ubuntu repository), `docker-ce` package (newer, from Docker repositories). If problem persists, then run `sudo apt-get update` and retry. If latter fails - check your repositories and reset them to default.

Answer (score 0):

It implies your sources.list is incorrect or you have not updated before running the command, it will install perfectly fine here if I took the -s off the end of the command. A paste.bin showing the results of it. Now I read my output again there is no docker.ce attempted to be installed. You need to determine where it comes from best by removing the * and replacing it by .io to actually install the package you want with its dependencies. `apt-get install docker docker.io -y` for that package as it seems to be what it is installing for me.

https://pastebin.com/WrhbCQgL

Comment: Thank everyone, I was able to install it with the new version of ubuntu